# Bitmap from longblob in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, bitmap

I have some images stored as `longblob`s in a remote MySQL database and I need to retrieve them for my Android application and display as a `Bitmap`. I have a PHP script setup to parse SQL queries to/from the Android application.

**What I have tried:**
I tried to get a String as below of the `longblob` field and then used `getBytes()` on it. But apparently, it isn't working. If I display the String, a huge number of characters (readable as well as unreadable) are displayed. So the problem is with encoding or converting from String to `byte[]` (I think).

```
StringBuilder strStream = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent()), 8);

String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) strStream.append(line);

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(strStream.toString().getBytes(), 0, strStream.length());
```

**What I Need:** Is there any way to create a `Bitmap` from a remote `longblob` stored in a `MySQL` database which I connect from Android using a custom PHP script? I'm perfectly sure the script is working correctly and my code is 100% working up to the variable `httpEntity`. I can even get the `String` and its the correct value. The only problem is, I can't get a `Bitmap`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler, the better :) PHP can output a blob from a database

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $result['blob'];
```

When you request this script with a web browser, you'll see a PNG image. Then the Android part

```
InputStream in = new URL("http://img.io/read.php").openStream();
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
in.close();
```

There's no need to pass through Strings here... Strings in Java are not simply byte arrays. They carry semantics, so the byte array is always coupled with an encoding scheme (which defaults to UTF-16LE)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I think it will work as expected, but just to make sure, I'll check it before choosing this as the correct answer. Thanks again :) +1

Comment: Sure :) may I ask if you really need to store the image in a DB? As you can see, it's a bit inefficient. If it were a file, Apache could simply serve it, but this way you have to make a connection to a DB server and let it read the filesystem for you. Consider this advice ;)

Comment: Do you have any examples of this? But still, I need the above code to read the `Bitmap`, right?

Comment: Example of what? Reading a DB with PHP? Create a `Bitmap` from an `InputStream`? It's not such a complex thing to test ;)

Comment: No, I meant the "...Apache could simply serve it...make a connection to a DB server and let it read the filesystem for you..." part.